# Typesense: Having an error timeout exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typesense

I am using Reactjs and having an issue with syncing data from Firestore to Typesense. I am following this documentation: https://typesense.org/docs/guide/firebase-full-text-search.html#step-1-run-typesense

Additionally, the following are the configurations I've done for my project based on the link above.

- Set up a Cloud Firestore database in my Firebase project.
- Setup a Typesense server (Self-Hosted)
- Setup a Typesense Collection through the API.
- Querying the data using simple search parameters
- The Instantsearch Adapter adapter is already installed and configured

The issue: it won't render the data and is having this error:

[image: Typesense Error]

Here's the code:

```
import "./App.css";
import { InstantSearch, SearchBox, Hits, Stats } from "react-instantsearch-dom";
import TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter from "typesense-instantsearch-adapter";
import Typesense from "typesense";

const client = new Typesense.Client({
  nodes: [
    {
      host: "13.54.222.245",
      port: "8108",
      protocol: "http",
    },
  ],
  apiKey: "admin_apikey",
  connectionTimeoutSeconds: 2,
});

// creating a collection
const eventData = {
  name: "events",
  fields: [
    { name: "eventName", type: "string" },
    { name: "eventInfo", type: "string[]" },
  ],
};
client
  .collections()
  .create(eventData)
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });

// query the data using search parameters
const search = {
  q: "events",
  query_by: "eventName",
};

client
  .collections("eventData")
  .documents()
  .search(search)
  .then(function (searchResults) {
    console.log(searchResults);
  });

// search interface for the client side
const typesenseInstantsearchAdapter = new TypesenseInstantSearchAdapter({
  server: {
    apiKey: "admin_apikey",
    nodes: [
      {
        host: "13.54.222.245",
        port: "8108",
        protocol: "http",
      },
    ],
  },
  additionalSearchParameters: {
    queryBy: "eventName, eventInfo",
  },
});
const searchClient = typesenseInstantsearchAdapter.searchClient;

function SearchInterface() {
  const Hit = ({ hit }) => (
    <section class="main">
      <div class="card-container">
        <div class="card-header">
          <h4>{hit.eventName}</h4>
          <p>{hit.eventInfo}</p>
        </div>
        <hr />
      </div>
    </section>
  );

  return (
    <InstantSearch searchClient={searchClient} indexName="eventData">
      <SearchBox />
      <Stats />
      <Hits hitComponent={Hit} />
    </InstantSearch>
  );
}
export default SearchInterface;
```

Here's what I got from the curl:

```
curl "http://13.54.222.245:8108/multi_search?x-typesense-api-key=admin_apikey" ^
  -H "Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" ^
  -H "Referer: http://localhost:3000/" ^
  -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Mobile Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.62" ^
  -H "Content-Type: text/plain" ^
  --data-raw "^{^\^"searches^\^":^[^{^\^"query_by^\^":^\^"eventName, eventInfo^\^",^\^"sort_by^\^":^\^"^\^",^\^"highlight_full_fields^\^":^\^"eventName, eventInfo^\^",^\^"collection^\^":^\^"eventData^\^",^\^"q^\^":^\^"*^\^",^\^"facet_by^\^":^\^"^\^",^\^"page^\^":1^}^]^}" ^
  --compressed
```

Comment: When I try visiting http://13.54.222.245:8108/health in my browser, it doesn't respond and times out. It's most likely the same issue that's also causing the timeout errors you're seeing in the browser console. Do you have a firewall that might prevent connections from all IPs?

Comment: I don't remember setting up a firewall since this is a new server that I've setup specifically for type sense. I disabled the firewall as well just in case, but still not working.

`ubuntu@ip-172-26-2-235:~/typesense$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive`

Comment: It looks like the app is having difficulty reaching the server. You mention you are self-hosting Typesense. Are you sure the hostname is correct? Are you running Typesense using WSL?